# How to make sure all transactions are, either, all committed or rolled back?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL procedure such as :

```
procedure MyProcedure() is 
begin 
    insert into table1 (field1, Field2) values ('value1','value2');

    -- do some staff

    insert into table2 (field1, Field2) values ('value1','value2');

    -- do some staff

    delete from table3 where id = xx;

    -- do some staff
end;
```

Some of the procedure instructions may fail and I would like to keep some coherence between all the instructions. That means if one instruction fails, I would like all the other instructions to be rolled back. So either everything is executed, or nothing is executed.

Does anyone know how to do that please ?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,

Comment: well you can add an exception, if any error occured an exception raised and you can add a rollback inside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can raise an exception if any error happen and rollback, if no error occured then you can add commit.
Note if in the future you add any DDL statements (create , alter ) the statements will be committed.

```
BEGIN

insert into table1 (field1, Field2) values ('value1','value2');

-- do some staff

insert into table2 (field1, Field2) values ('value1','value2');

-- do some staff

delete from table3 where id = xx;
commit;
  -- if any error occured
   WHEN OTHERS THEN  
 rollback;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end make either a `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` - that's it. Of course, you will get intended behavior only if you don't have any command in between which performs an implicit COMMIT, e.g. `TRUNCATE TABLE ...`

Answer (score 1):

Transaction control should preferably happen where it's invoked and not inside the procedure, unless it's an autonomous transaction.

```
procedure MyProcedure( ret_status out int ) is
..
..
```

**Invocation** ( Could be another procedure/ block or Web application)

```
DECLARE
     v_ret_status   INTEGER;
BEGIN
     myprocedure(v_ret_status);
     IF
          v_ret_status = 0
     THEN
          COMMIT;
     ELSE
          ROLLBACK;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Also, preferably call a logging procedure or a `dbms_output` with the relevant error message in the exception section.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is more or less the default behaviour:

```
create table test1 (id integer not null);
create table test2 (id integer not null);
create table test3 (id integer not null);

create or replace procedure myProcedure
    ( p1 test1.id%type
    , p2 test2.id%type
    , p3 test3.id%type )
as
begin
    insert into test1 (id) values (p1);
    insert into test2 (id) values (p2);
    insert into test3 (id) values (p3);
end myProcedure;
/

call myProcedure(1, 2, 3);
-- completes successfully

call myProcedure(1, 2, null);
-- fails with:
-- ERROR at line 1:
-- ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WILLIAM"."TEST3"."ID")
-- ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.MYPROCEDURE", line 9

select 'test1' as table_name, test1.id from test1 union all
select 'test2', test2.id from test2 union all
select 'test3', test3.id from test3
order by 1;

TABLE         ID
----- ----------
test1          1
test2          2
test3          3

3 rows selected.
```

So I have the three rows from the call that succeeded, and nothing from the call that failed, all without explicitly committing or rolling back.

You can add a `commit` to the end of the procedure if you really want it to commit (not always a good idea, but requirements vary).

**However**, the default "rollback to implicit savepoint" behaviour only takes place if the exception propagates all the way up to the caller, so for example if I attempt to handle it with:

```
begin
    delete test1;
    delete test2;
    delete test3;

    myProcedure(1, 2, null);
exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
        dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
end;

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WILLIAM"."TEST3"."ID")
ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.MYPROCEDURE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Now, because the block completed successfully, I have the values from the run that failed part way through:

```
select 'test1' as table_name, test1.id from test1 union all
select 'test2', test2.id from test2 union all
select 'test3', test3.id from test3
order by 1;

TABLE         ID
----- ----------
test1          1
test2          2

2 rows selected.
```

Anyway, to handle all this explicitly, you might want something like this:

```
create or replace procedure myProcedure
    ( p1 test1.id%type
    , p2 test2.id%type
    , p3 test3.id%type )
as
begin
    savepoint start_of_processing;

    insert into test1 (id) values (p1);
    insert into test2 (id) values (p2);
    insert into test3 (id) values (p3);

    commit;
exception
    when others then
        rollback to start_of_processing;
        -- Log using whatever logging package you have:
        logger.message('Something appears to have gone disastrously amiss');
        raise;
end myProcedure;
```

Bear in mind, though, that [the act of observing an exception changes it irrevocably](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/plsql-error-logging-and-quantum-theory). As far as I know this is true in all programming languages.